# Assign return value of function to variable

Tags: javascript

I kind of got the same question as has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941381/assign-function-return-value-to-some-variable-using-javascript).

I've made a function:

```
const rewardStayingViewersOrNewcomers = () => {
  fetch('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters')
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(r => {
    let chatters = r.chatters;
    viewerKeys = Object.keys(chatters); // [mods, viewers,...]
    let ChattersPerRole = viewerKeys.map(role => {
      return chatters[role].map(username => ({
        username, role
      }));
    });
    return flattenDeep(ChattersPerRole);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(`Error in fetch: ${err}`);
  });
};
```

Why can't I assign that return value to my variable? The log of that variable returns undefined...

```
let viewersPerRole = rewardStayingViewersOrNewcomers();
setTimeout(() => console.log(viewersPerRole), 7000);
```

*Bonus question*, how could I easily wait for viewersPerRole to be filled with the data I'm waiting for because of the fetch? (so I don't have to use setTimeout())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try returning something from the main function. There's no return in front on the fetch(...). Code should look like:

```
const rewardStayingViewersOrNewcomers = () => {
  return fetch('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters')
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(r => {
    let chatters = r.chatters;
    viewerKeys = Object.keys(chatters); // [mods, viewers,...]
    let ChattersPerRole = viewerKeys.map(role => {
      return chatters[role].map(username => ({
        username, role
      }));
    });
    return Promise.resolve(flattenDeep(ChattersPerRole));
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(`Error in fetch: ${err}`);
  });
};

// now that you're returning a promise
rewardStayingViewersOrNewcomers()
  .then(viewersPerRole => console.log(viewersPerRole))
```

If you're using Babeljs to transpile with stage3 enabled, have a look at async / await.

Comment: Why do you _have_ to put the return in front of the fetch?

Comment: You need to return a value that will be the result of calling rewardStayingViewersOrNewcomers(). If you don't do that, the result will be undefined.

Comment: Well, I was returning data by: `return flattenDeep(ChattersPerRole);`, no?

Comment: That was being *to* the rewardStayingViewersOrNewcomers() not *from*. If you do `let foo = fetch() ...` then foo was the result of `return flattenDeep(ChattersPerRole);`. Not if you want to have a return value from the rewardStayingViewersOrNewcomers() function, you just need to `return foo;` at the end. I just cut the middle man and returned it directly.