# Assigning DOM event to variable or array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Building a card matching game, full code here https://codepen.io/3noki/pen/xjyErQ

I am trying to assign the event of turning a card over to a list/array, or a variable I guess, so I can check if it matches the next event of turning a second card over. But, this example, is resulting in errors, was placed this in the function `openedCards()`.

```
let card1 =  $(event.target).toggleClass('open show');
```

If there is a better method for matching a value to a later value I haven't learned it yet, but this is what I currently know.

Also, I have implemented a counter, which should increment to a value of 1, then next event to a value of 2, and if they don't match, reset the both cards, I will be able to test it after this first part works, but that is listed in the function `openedCards()`.

I think the biggest thing I am struggling with is specifying or saving the 1st and 2nd events from the DOM or figuring out how to reference this event as in an array[this event].

I've looked at some other examples like below but have been unsuccessful with trying those.

[assign function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941381/assign-function-return-value-to-some-variable-using-javascript)

[array of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908378/javascript-array-of-functions)

Excerpt of the code

```
function cardFlip(event) { 
    $(event.target).toggleClass('open show') 
    openedCards();
} 

function openedCards(i) { 
    if (openedCardsList.length === 0) {
        openedCardsList.push(i); 
         let card1 = $(event.target).toggleClass('open show');
    } else if (openedCardsList.length === 1) { 
        openedCardsList.push(i); 
        let card2 = $(event.target).toggleClass('open show');
    } else {
        openedCardsList = []; 
        cardFlip(card1);  
        cardFlip(card2);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to ask. Please narrow down your question to *one* specific problem, and post the relevant code, what you expect to happen, and what's happening instead, in detail. I also have a feeling you're using the term "event" wrong; you can't "assign an event to a list".

Comment: How could I save the cardFlip() so I can check it against the second cardFlip()?

`function cardFlip(event) {
 $(event.target).toggleClass('open show')
 openedCards();
}
function openedCards(i) {
  if (openedCardsList.length === 0) {
    openedCardsList.push(i);
    let card1 =  $(event.target).toggleClass('open show');
  }
  else if (openedCardsList.length === 1) {
    openedCardsList.push(i);
    let card2 =  $(event.target).toggleClass('open show');
  }
  else{
    openedCardsList = [];
    cardFlip(card1);
    cardFlip(card2);
  }`

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code, it's illegible in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `openedCards` accepts a single paramneter `i`. you are not passing any value to `openedCards` when calling it from `cardFlip` so you are pushing `undefined` to `openedCardsList`.

Second, you are calling `$(event.target).toggleClass('open show');` in both `cardFlip` and `openedCards`.  Since you are toggling, it would be better to only toggle when needed rather than toggle and then untoggle in certain cases.

Third, you are setting the values of `card1` and `card2` in separate blocks of your conditional so they will never be defined in your `else` block:

```
function openedCards(i) {
  if (openedCardsList.length === 0) {
    openedCardsList.push(i);
    let card1 =  $(event.target).toggleClass('open show');
  }
  else if (openedCardsList.length === 1) {
    openedCardsList.push(i);
    let card2 =  $(event.target).toggleClass('open show');
  }
  else{
    openedCardsList = [];
    // card1 and card2 are undefined here
    cardFlip(card1);
    cardFlip(card2);
  }
}
```

Lastly, `myElem.toggle` returns `myElem` not an event or a value so you should track the class of the card that's flipped and use that to compare since the class names of identical cards should always match.

I would get rid of the nested functions and use a single function to track the last card with:

```
let lastCard = null;

function cardFlip(event) {
  const thisCard = $(event.target);
  const cardClass = $(event.target).children("i").className;

  thisCard.toggleClass('open show')

  if (lastCard) {
    if (lastCard !== thisCard) {
        // The cards don't match
        cardFlip(lastCard);
        cardFlip(thisCard);
    } else {
      // you found a match!!!
      matchedCards++
    }
    lastCard = null;
  } else {
    // This is the first card flipped
    lastCard = cardClass;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I ended up using, but this helped me understand a different way to look at this.